# Interrupted kernel upgrade?

Tags: dual-boot, kernel

I got distracted during a software upgrade of my 20.04 machine today. I have Windows 10, 18.04 and 20.04 on the machine, and all was working well . . . until I intervened . . .

I forgot that I was told that a restart was needed in order to complete the upgrade; and I rebooted into 18.04 to fetch some code.

So, I could not boot into 20.04, nor in recovery mode, using 5.8.0-44. (I think that is called a kernel?)

After spending time looking at options, I decided to try boot-repair from my 'live-cd' 20.04. No go. Windows and 18.04 are fine.

So, I tried booting into the previous kernel (5.8.0-43), and it worked. That makes it look to me like I interrupted a kernel upgrade. OTOH, I noted upon reboot (Grub) that I am now running 20.04.2, while I pretty sure that I have been running 20.04.1. Basically, I am not sure what happened.

I have two questions:

1. How do I fix/use the newest kernel? (I saw older questions about interrupted software upgrades, but did not see one dealing with interrupted kernel upgrades.)
2. Is it safe to install and run boot-repair from the 20.04 that I run on the system?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Since you can boot into 20.04 using an older kernel, boot-repair won't help you. You don't have a boot-related problem. Try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic` to re-install that particular kernel package. If you encounter any error messages, copy/paste your entire output into your question above so we can see it. If you encounter NO error messages, try rebooting into the new kernel.

Comment: user535733: Thank you! That worked wrt rebooting. I want to rerun boot-repair to hopefully remove a couple of entries to the grub page added during last execution of boot repair. I had forgotten to remove a couple of HDs containing machine backups before running it. Is it OK/safe to install and run boot-repair on my "production" 20.04?

Comment: My threshold of "OK/Safe" may differ from yours. I consider boot-repair an emergency tool that might sometimes do something unexpected. You can do it, but it would not be my first choice. Were it my system, and it's bootable, I would instead look up how to edit GRUB so I have greater visibility in the process and confidence in the result.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. There are sites that suggest running boot-repair on the bootable OS of a mulit-boot system. I chose to go the live-Ubuntu route rather than running it on my 18.04, because it seemed safer. I will first look into editing grub, as you suggest. Thanks again.